# SQL select where in as intersection instead of a union

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'll explain the problem with examples so it is easy to understand, given the following data structure:

```
id  userId  
1   1    
1   2    
2   2    
3   2    
1   3     
2   3
```

I can get a list of `id`s for a set of users as follows:

```
declare @tmp table (id int, userId int)
insert into @tmp values(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (1,3), (2,3)


select id from @tmp
where userId in (1,2,3)
group by id
```

This will return the following as expected:

```
id
1
2
3
```

My question is, how can I only get the ids that have mapping for **EVERY** userId in the `where` clause? e.g. the result for `userId in (1,2,3)` should be `1` and for `userId in (2,3)` should be `1,2`

I've tried going through each id and then merging those but so far had no luck on finding an actual solution.

**NOTE** The solution must work for larger data sets, imagine millions of rows and thousands of userIds, efficiency of the solution is not as important (as it does not have to run very often)

**Second NOTE** I just noticed that counting the result does not actually guarantee correctness, because two different userIds may have the same count of mappings but mapped to different Items. In that scenario it is not an intersection anymore

Comment: How will you pass useid's to `where` clause?

Comment: @uzi you can pass the userIds in any way you want, just assume we have a list of integers that represent userIds, It can be any form of query you want as longs as it works in all cases and matches the specs

Comment: @Arijoon so, are you saying we could use a delimited list, or a Custom Table-Type?

Comment: Yes you can use whatever you want, custom/temp table, loop, delimited list, string list, anything

Comment: Arijoon, have you considered validating `id` with an aggregate? Count the distinct records in the userid table, and then `count(distinct id)` where the count matches, the `id` is valid

Comment: I think so too. I would just add `having count(distinct userid) = 3` to the query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a count of user IDs to check... Like this

```
SELECT Id
From table
Where userid in (1,2,3)
Group by id
Having count(userid) = (select count(distinct userid) from table where userid in(1,2,3))
```

Ideally the 2 conditions get parameterized, but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Nice, this logic is exactly what I had in mind, but couldn't actually SQL up. Still interesting to see if anyone can come up with another way

Comment: This query is flawed. If the table happens to only contain records for userid 1 and 2, you'd get wrong results (i.e. all IDs that match users 1 and 2 rather than no rows).

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I note your answer has the same problem. Only way around it i can think of is to get the user IDs into a list.

Comment: No, my answer doesn't have the same problem. It assumes to work only on valid user IDs, for which it uses the users table. That is different. If OP wanted the query to be error-aware (i.e. not return results when a user ID is invalid), they'd have to replace my users subquery with a mere value clause. Your query can return wrong results even when all user IDs are valid.

Comment: If the userid is in the database at all select distinct userid will find it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used temp table to store userids

```
declare @tmp table (id int, userId int)
insert into @tmp values(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (1,3), (2,3)

declare @userid table (id int)
insert into @userid values (1), (2), (3)

select
    t.id
from 
    (select *, cnt = count(*) over () from @userid) u
    join @tmp t on u.id = t.userId
group by t.id, u.cnt
having u.cnt = count(distinct u.id)
```

Comment: Just to point out, that's not a Temporary Table, it's a Table Variable. The 2 are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is that you want to specify the user IDs just once, use your user table:

```
with u as (select userid from users where userid in (1,2,3))
select id 
from mytable
where userid in (select userid from u)
group by id
having count(distinct userid) = (select count(*) from u);
```

If you wanted to react on invalid user IDs with an empty result set, you'd replace the users table with a values clause:

```
with u as (select userid from (values (1), (2), (3)) AS ids(userid))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a `count distinct` as well as having to enter your `userId` values more than once - or at all if you populate the equivalent of the `@i` dataset from a dynamic query:

```
declare @t table (id int, userId int);
insert into @t values(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (1,3), (2,3);

declare @i table (i int);
insert into @i values(1),(2),(3);

select t.id
from @i as i
    join @t as t
        on i.i = t.userId
group by t.id
having count(i.i) = (select count(1) from @i);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT id
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN UserID = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN UserID = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN UserID = 3 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: You have specified UserId case by case, this is not really what I had in mind, I'll update the question to specify the case, we could have millions of rows and different users in that table

Comment: @Arijoon: I don't see what your problem with Larnu's answer is. Looks fine to me and your edited request doesn't say anything against it either.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The problem is the Op is saying that they might be passing say ID `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9...49, 50.`. Thus, they would need 50 `HAVING` clauses.

Comment: Well, who cares? That's just copy and paste. And if done from an app it's a mere loop to create the query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The OP does, they are the one asking the question, and putting the line in the sand. ;)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it's not a copy and paste, here you need to know the count for each userId, but in reality you don't when there are millions of rows, so that needs to be calculated as part of the query like the other answers have suggested.

Comment: @Arijoon: No. In the example you want three user IDs. Rather than putting the three numbers into the parentheses in `where userid in (1,2,3)` you put three lines in the having clause. Not much of a difference to me actually.